# Access Denied when trying to access a json file for the second time

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am able to access a file once on Initialization, but can't access it a second time.

First access:

```
static Gun()
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(AppSettings))
        {
            Settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(sr.ReadToEnd());
            sr.Close();
        }
```

Second Access:

```
 public static void Save()
    {
        // Changing to StreamReader doesn't work either
        using (var sr = new StreamWriter(AppSettings))
        {
            var settings = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Settings);
            sr.WriteLineAsync(settings);
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
```

When I try to access it a second time I get an unauthorized access exception. Not a file in use, but rather unauthorized. Why would the scope or permission of my project change within the same app?

Comment: You haven't posted any code or meaningful detail about what you're doing so there is very little we can do to help you.  Please read [ask] for guidance in writing a good on topic question

Comment: with iOS and Android, you can't write to files that are embedded in the app bundle.  I suspect this is true of UWP too, but I'm not positive

Comment: @Jason, maybe, but as mentioned in the comment, doesn't help for string reader either.

Comment: Could mind share more code that how to get AppSettings json file ?

Comment: what's the type of AppSettings parameter, path string or `Stream`?

Comment: You have "read" permission to this resource, you must set "read/write".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Access Denied when trying to access a json file for the second time

In general we suggest you store the setting file in UWP app local storage. it has full permission to access.

For example

```
string settingFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "SettingFile.json");

public void GetSetting()
{

    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(settingFile))
    {
        var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(json);
        reader.Close();
    }
}

public void Save()
{

    using (var sr = new StreamWriter(settingFile))
    {
        var newSetting = new Settings()
        {
            ID = "SGML"`enter code here`  
        };
        var settings = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newSetting);
        sr.WriteLineAsync(settings);
        sr.Close();
    }
}
```